# Yeast sediment after bottling

Tags: sediment

I've now bottled all of my brew and I saw there was a very thin layer of sediment at the bottom of the bucket. I've read some reports about an inch thick sediment at the bottom of a 5 gallon bucket. Has something gone wrong with mine?

Comment: If you left an inch in the bucket, then you have only small amount in suspension, and thus in bottles. These are separate steps so of course results cannot be directly compared. What is your problem?

Comment: We need more information about your process...  what type of brew is it?  Is it all grain? From a kit?  How long did you let it sit before bottling?

Comment: What was being brewed? Was the progress of the fermentation followed using a hydrometer? Was any fermentation evident in the vessel (eg bubbling, krausen formation, etc). Was the bottled brew clear or cloudy?

Comment: Brewed from a Brigalow homebrew kit. Nice and clear in the bottles. The last 2 I poured was a bit cloudy but I marked them so I could compare the taste when ready. I started my brew on the 18th of Dec and bottled on the 2nd of Jan. Yes I did use a hydrometer and my  final 3 readings over 3 days was 1004. Very very slow bubble (a bubble every 15-20 sec.) At the end.

Answer (score 2):

If the brew went well then there is probably a lot of yeast left in solution and it will precipitate in the bottle. If the brew was not so complete then keep a watch on your bottles for excessive pressure! If all else fails then remember that "bottle conditioning" over many months can cure a multitude of sins.... as well as rendering an undrinkable brew "fit for drunken friends".

I note from the comment above that this was an extract brew, the brew was reasonably clear and the FG was 1004. From that I would deduce this was a light beer/ale/lager and fermentation had proceeded to completion. I am presuming some priming sugar/drops was added before sealing the bottles. On the face of it, this beer should be good to go after a few weeks of conditioning in the bottle. My advice would be to leave it a bit longer rather than a bit shorter to condition fully. Use the waiting time to brew your next batch! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you hit your FG then I would not worry too much. I have had some brews with thick sludgy yeast cakes and others with shallow compact yeast cakes from the same yeast.

As the comments above ask, some more details would be helpful, a picture or two can also be helpful.